# nginx "http_headers_more" module returns "not binary compatible" error

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to run the `nginx-mod-http-headers-more` module for nginx so that I can fully hide the server name/version from a header response.

A bit of background, I am running nginx 1.16.1 inside a docker container. It has a dockerfile running `nginx:1.16.1-alpine`. In order to hide the `Server` header response field I need to use the `nginx-mod-http-headers-more` module.

I added the following commands into my dockerfile to get the module installed in my docker container:

```
RUN apk update && \
apk upgrade && \ 
apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more
```

Inside my `nginx.conf` file, I added the following lines:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;
...
http {
   server {
      more_clear_headers   "Server: ";
      ...
   }
}
```

The `load_module` statement and the `more_clear_headers` are the two pieces of code needed to make this module work.
However when the docker container is created and ran, it generates this error inside the container:

```
nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I need help to figure out what to do from here! Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a response to this?